# Call on android through sip

Tags: android, sip

I am using android.net.sip library and i am able to registered and call but i am unable to hear voice
It showing 
E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
E/AudioGroup: cannot initialize audio device
Can anyboy help me about that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not manually take this permission 
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WelcomeScreenActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 3);

after use this it is working fine for me